# How to redirect all pages of particular sub-domain to another sub-domain using Apache?

Tags: apache2

I would like to redirect all references of an absolute path (`source.toto.org`) to another absolute path (`git.toto.org`). This link is in many pages and I do not wish to change the page contents. I tried to modify my site's `.htaccess` file but I don't think my syntax is incorrect:

```
Redirect source.toto.org http://git.toto.org
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the syntax should be:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect / http://git.toto.org
```

Comment: If that syntax is not what you wish, you will need to be more specific or see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: I will be more specific :)

One of my pages has a link towards source.toto.org. I do not wish to edit the page, but I want to redirect this link towards git.toto.org. Most examples are for relative paths.

Comment: You mean re-direct when people click on your link ? Or incoming traffic? Just one page ?

Comment: Well, although it does not answer your question, for a single link on a single page, I would update the link. `sed -i -e 's_source.toto.org_git.toto.org_g'`. You can also use javascript to re-write the link. You can try Redirect or personally I would Rewrite. `Redirect http://source.toto.org http://git.toto.org` or `RewriteRule    ^source.toto.org$  git.toto.org  [R,L]`